# Can one git repository track subversion and git remotes?

Tags: git, git-svn, multiple-repositories

I am going to set up extra repositories for our partners, while our official repository is svn, I am free to pick the repositories for our partners.

My idea is to clone our repo with git-svn(let's call this repo1), create git repositories for our partners and track partner repositories with repo1. Is this possible without making git-svn confused?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're suggesting is unsupported out-of-the-box with git-svn.  The core code considers git-svn to be a git-like svn client, but not a full blown git repository environment.  Here's an excerpt from [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion), a free online manual with great details on git-svn:

> Don’t set up and collaborate on a separate Git server. Possibly have one to speed up clones for new developers, but don’t push anything to it that doesn’t have a git-svn-id entry. You may even want to add a pre-receive hook that checks each commit message for a git-svn-id and rejects pushes that contain commits without it.

Reason has to do with how git-svn assigns git-svn-id's.  For your use case I would try [Subgit](http://subgit.com/).  Allows full integration between a git repository network and a legacy SVN repo.

Comment: Not what I was looking for, however looks very interesting.

Comment: I updated with an explanation.  Git-svn doesn't really support the use case you're describing out of the box, hence the recommended alternative.